# invoke fsi on memory (not file)

Tags: f#, fsi

Let's say we have a fsi script like this:

```
#r "System.Core.dll"
let script = "Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, World!\")"
// fsi script ???
```

We can use #load to invoke fsi on a file, but is it possible to somehow invoke fsi on an in-memory string without writing that to a file first?

The use-case is an API compatibility tester: given a dll, I would like to create a script that invocations all its public APIs and compile that script against a different version of the same dll.

I could always write the generated script to disk, but it would be much cleaner if I could run it directly.

Comment: Could you write it to `stdin` of the FSI process?

Comment: This might actually work, it just feels like a terrible hack :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tasks of kind you outlined in your question may be performed with tools provided within [`Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee842571.aspx) namespace, in particular, with the help of type [`FsiEvaluationSession`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/fsi/fsi.fs#l2219) of `Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell`.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/panesofglass/5989138) authored by [Ryan Riley](https://github.com/panesofglass) demoes exactly your scenario using a thin wrapper type `FSharpEngine` over `FsiEvaluationSession`, making programmatic use of `fsi` as convenient as:

```
....
let engine = new FSharpEngine()
engine.Execute("<some F# code>") |> processOutput
....
engine.Dispose()
```